# How to switch all the columns from sortable to not sortable (and back)?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm pretty new to ext.js (3.4), and I really struggle to implement such a simple feature :

I have a Grid, with a ColumModel where sortable is explicitly sets to false. All columns are sortable or not sortable, there is no case where some may be sortable while other won't.

I'd like to be find an easy and simple way to switch them between those two states, but I'm stuck.
I guess that i should use columnModel.setConfig(), but i can't find any code sample that is not over-complex or completely unrelated.

Can one of you gives me a hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.getCmp('your-grid-id').getColumnModel().getColumnById('your-column-id').sortable=true;
```

**EDIT-**
To switch states of ALL columns-

```
Ext.each(Ext.getCmp('your-grid-id').getColumnModel().config, function(c){c.sortable=!c.sortable});
```

Comment: This way, I'll have to explicitly set each column to sortable/not sortable. I was searching for a way to do it in all at once :)

Comment: see edit. also, suggestion - ExtJS API doc is your friend. get to know it. -:)

Comment: Thank you very much ! ExtJS API will be my friend soon, trust me ;)